# C# - Reflection and method properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an attribute called `NetworkEventAttribute` which includes an enum in it's properties so I can identify it.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class NetworkEventAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Messages Message { get; private set; }

    public NetworkEventAttribute(Messages message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }
}
```

I have several classes which inherit from my `NetworkEvent` abstract class that I tag using this attribute and each class includes a different enum value, for example:

```
[NetworkEvent(Messages.SomeMessage)]
public class SomeEvent : NetworkEvent
{
    public override void Handle(Client client)
}

public abstract class NetworkEvent
{
    public Rider Rider { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }

    public abstract void Handle(Client client, InPacket inPacket);
}
```

Now. I want to call `Handle` on a class based on the given enum. So I know I can get all the methods of a certain attribute like so:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Doublet<TAttribute, MethodInfo>> FindMethodsByAttribute<TAttribute>()
         where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return
            from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from t in a.GetTypes()
            let attribute = t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TAttribute), false) as TAttribute
            where attribute != null
            select new Doublet<TAttribute, MethodInfo>(attribute, t.GetMethod("Handle"));
    }
```

However, I also want to set the `Rider` and `Room` properties **before** calling the method.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** I made the reflection method return  `IEnumerable<Doublet<TAttribute, Type>>` and then I made my get method return the type like so:

```
public NetworkEvent GetHandler(Messages message, Client client, InPacket inPacket)
    {
        if (!_handlers.ContainsKey(message))
            return null;

        NetworkEvent handler = (NetworkEvent)Activator.CreateInstance(_handlers[message]);
        handler.Rider = client.Rider;
        handler.Room = client.Rider?.Room;

        return handler;
    }
```

And then I just call:

```
var handler = Server.Instance.GetHandler(inPacket.Message, this, inPacket);
                if (handler == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Unhandled packet of type '{0}'.", inPacket.Message.ToString());
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        handler.GetType().GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler.GetType(), new object[2] { this, inPacket });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error while handling packet from {0}: \n{1}", this.Host, ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your current code finds the `MethodInfo` based on the type. Setting property values is something you do on instances (these are not static properties). Show us your code where you call the method, and it should be trivial to just set those properties before you invoke the method on the instance.

Comment: How do you actually create your `NetworkEvent`s?

Comment: @odyss-jii That is my question. I'm returning the MethodInfo but that would only work on static methods. My question is how I can create an instance of the classes with the properties and call the method.

Comment: @Evk I added to the edit.

Comment: It's almost fine, except you don't need to do `handler.GetType().GetMethod("Handle")`, because your `handler` is already of type `NetworkEvent`, so you can just call `handler.Handle(this, inPacket)`